# jQuery UI tabs with HTML forms: Working in Firefox, Broken in IE

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

Edit: Here's the jsFiddle, which shows the page working as it should - http://jsfiddle.net/KH3bs/3/

Edit2: Works in IE9 with compatibility mode on, doesn't work if it is off.

If I put any other code in my tabs, they work equally well in both Firefox and IE. What I want, though, are forms in my tabs, and as soon as I do this, they break in IE (I'm using IE9 in particular).

These are the scripts and style sheets being called in the master file:

```
<link href="http://www.stmartin.edu/styles/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://www.stmartin.edu/styles/2col.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://www.stmartin.edu/library/css/OGrady.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.stmartin.edu/scripts/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is the page with my tabs & forms:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" masterpagefile="_master/content_2_column.master" title="Saint Martin's University" %> <asp:Content id="Content1" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="headerImage">
<img alt="" src="images/libBicycle.jpg" width="1130" height="149" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../social/styles/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />

                <script>
                $(function() {
                                $("#tabs").tabs();
                });
                </script>

                <style type="text/css">

                #tabs {
                                                                display:block;
                                                                overflow:auto;

}

                </style>

</asp:Content>


<asp:Content id="Content2" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="pageContent">

<h1>O&#39;Grady Library</h1>

<p style="font-weight=bold;">Quick search</p>

 <div id="tabs" style="width: 103%; font-size: .8em;">         
        <ul>
          <li style="width: 23%;"><a href="#tabs-1">Books</a></li>
          <li style="width: 23%;"><a href="#tabs-2">Articles</a></li>
          <li style="width: 23%;"><a href="#tabs-3">DVDs</a></li>
          <li style="width: 23%;"><a href="#tabs-4">Everything</a></li>
        </ul>       

         <div id="tabs-0">
            <form class="search" action="http://stmartin.worldcat.org/search" method="get">
            </form>
        </div> 


       <div id="tabs-1">
          <h2>Search the Library Catalog for Books</h2>
        <form class="search" action="http://stmartin.worldcat.org/search" method="get">
          <input type="hidden" name="fq" value="x0:book">
          <input type="text" maxlength="65" size="30" name="q">
          <input type="submit" value="GO">
            </form>
        </div>  

        <div id="tabs-2">
          <h2>Search the Library Catalog for Articles</h2>
            <form class="search" action="http://stmartin.worldcat.org/search" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="fq" value="x0:artchap">
            <input type="text" maxlength="65" size="30" name="q">
            <input type="submit" value="GO">
        </form>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-3">
          <h2>Search the Library Catalog for DVDs</h2>
            <form class="search" action="http://stmartin.worldcat.org/search" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="fq" value="x0:video">
            <input type="text" maxlength="65" size="30" name="q">
            <input type="submit" value="GO">
        </form>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-4">
          <h2>Search the Library Catalog for Everything</h2>
            <form class="search" action="http://stmartin.worldcat.org/search" method="get">
            <input type="text" maxlength="65" size="30" name="q">
            <input type="submit" value="GO">
        </form>

        </div>
      </div>



</asp:Content>

<asp:Content id="Content3" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="rightContent">

<h1>Library hours Spring 2012</h1>

<table cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Mon-Thu </td>
<td align="right">7:30 am</td>
<td align="center">-</td>
<td align="right">11 pm</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Fri</td>
<td align="right">7:30 am</td>
<td align="center">-</td>
<td align="right">5 pm</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Sat</td>
<td align="right">10 am</td>
<td align="center">-</td>
<td align="right">6 pm</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Sun</td>
<td align="right">1 pm</td>
<td align="center">-</td>
<td align="right">9 pm</td></tr>
</table>


<p>&nbsp;<br /> 
<a href="about/hours.aspx">See details</a> for holidays<br />
<a href="../about/ClosurePolicy.aspx">Campus closure policy</a></p>
<p><a href="jobs/"><strong>Employment opportunities</strong></a></p>


<p>
<a href="guides/bridge.aspx"> Personal Librarian</a> program</p>

</asp:Content>
```

There is a blank form in tab-0 because Firefox was refusing to submit whatever form was listed first (for some reason) so this is a sloppy fix. Either way, it doesn't work in IE.

Firefox looks exactly as it should. In IE9, however, I can't switch between tabs, and all of the forms end up listed down the page vertically all at once. The forms, such as they are, do work in IE, but obviously the point of putting them behind jquery tabs was so that they wouldn't all display at the same time.

IE8 is working better - it will switch between tabs and only lists the active tab's form, but it bumps the form down halfway down the page. Both versions of IE are having some sort of clear problem and are bumping content down in the sidebar to the left as well.

If I change the content in the tabs to anything that isn't a  then the tabs will work in IE. We have the same tabs working on another page (http://www.stmartin.edu/social/) and they're just fine, so it's definitely the  field that doesn't want to play nice, for whatever reason.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try closing you input-tags

```
<input type="text" maxlength="65" size="30" name="q" />
```

all your input-tags are open. Not sure if thats the problem, but give it a try - maybe set up a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks! I closed the input tags, but it didn't help. I set up a jsFiddle, which shows the page working as it should:

http://jsfiddle.net/KH3bs/3/

Answer (score 0):

Since compatibility mode worked in IE9, I forced IE7 emulation with a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

It works, but it's not a super solution. Other suggestions are still welcome.